# Caching system capacity with Play

Tags: caching, playframework

I need a fast short term memory to use with my Play app (2.5).
I was thinking about using the cache system. However, even though, if the data I am gonna store in the cache will expire after 10 minutes, I may need to store hundred of millions rows. Is the Play cache appropriate for a such job, or should I look into a db (as MongoDB) solution here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is EHCache which is pretty well proven and robust and can scale. So millions of entries should not be a problem if you have the means to support your requirements in terms of resources.

I tend to use Redis since I am more comfortable with it but have built several applications with EHCache with no problems at all.

The question of performance is more to do with how you configure it ie. how much memory you give to the cache heap, whether you distribute it if your application grows that large etc.